# Not able to generate server-config.wsdd using Eclipse and Tomcat 7.0

Tags: web-services, tomcat7, axis, eclipse-juno, jax-rpc

I am trying to generate the Web Service using the the following steps but **could not generate the server-config.wsdd** and the below message is shown:

```
**Jul 04, 2013 10:51:23 PM org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet getServerEngineConfig
SEVERE: Unable to find config file.  Creating new servlet engine config file: /WEB-INF/server-config.wsdd**

Eclipse Version : Juno bit
Tomcat Version: 7.0.41  32 bit
Platform: Windows 7 32 bit
JRE: jre7
```

Steps:
Create Dynamic Web Project and assiciate it with 
Create Class under package: com.sample.service.SampleWebService.java
Click on File/New/Others/**Web Service** project.
Choose **Bottom Up Java Bean Web Service** as **Web Service Type**
Provide the Path of the Java File along with the above mention package.

Choose **Tomcat** as server and Axis as **Web Service Rum Time**

Click Next and then choose the method to be exposed as web service

Rename the WSDL File Name in the Text Box
Style Use: **document/literal (wrapped)**
Click Next 
Press Start Server.
Press Next:

Exception:

```
**faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
&#160;faultSubcode:
&#160;faultString: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:"HTML";**
```

Note: This is simple Web service and I haven't used Annotation.